# Laravel TALL sql server Illuminate/Database/Connection.php General error 20018 UPDATE failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings

Tags: sql-server, laravel-livewire

I am programming a content editable datatable with Livewire. The database is an external MS SQL Server.

In this case in particular, I got a `users` datatable, where there's this column that comes from a `belongsTo()` relationship: `areas` table. In this example, the user clicks right on a row (of the area column) and a select area component renders. When the user clicks on an option, livewire triggers an update method and re-renders the table with the new value (what i am actually pretending to achieve). However, right at the moment of saving the model. I get that error.

Here's my code:
**User.php**

```
class User extends Model
{
    use Notifiable;
    /**
     * External DB connection on MSSQL SERVER.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $connection='ext'; //external MS SQL Server
   /**
    * Indicates if the model should be timestamped.
    *
    * @var bool
    */
    public $timestamps = false;
    /************
     ******************** R  E  L  A  T  I  O  N  S  H  I  P  S  ********************
     ***********/

    public function area()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Area::class,'area_id');
    }
}
```

**Area.php**

```
class Area extends Model
{

    /**
     * External DB connection on MSSQL SERVER
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $connection='ext';//external MS SQL Server
    /**
     * Indicates if the model should be timestamped.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

When you click on a specific row of that column, livewire calls another component that renders a select option.

```
<td wire:click.prevent="editAreaColumn({{$record->area->id}},{{$record->id}})" class="px-6 py-4">
    @if($identifier!='' && $identificador==$record->id){{-- && $editAreaId==$record->area->id--}}
       @livewire('path.to.select-area',['area_id'=>$record->area->id,'record_id'=>$record->id])
    @elseif($identifier == '' && $identifier != $record->id){{--&& $editAreaId=='' && $editAreaId!=$record->area->id--}}
          <div class="text-sm text-gray-900">{{$record->area->name}}</div>
    @else
         <div class="text-sm text-gray-700">{{$record->area->name}}</div>
    @endif
</td>
```

That component loads the data catalog of that relational table.
[image: Livewire datatable content editable]

So far so good. I have programmed so that when you click on an option, livewire triggers an update method. Inside the `HTML select` blade component I got the following:

```
<div wire:init="loadData">
    <div class="m-2 relative">
        @if($readyToLoad)
            @if($areas->count()>0)
                <select class="text-xs appearance-none border border-gray-200 py-1 px-3 w-full truncate rounded-lg" id="area_id">
                    <option value="" selected hidden>Choose</option>
                    @foreach($areas as $area)
                        <option wire:click="updateArea({{$area->id}})" value="{{ $area->id }}">{{ $area->name }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
                <div class="border-gray-400 border-r border-b p-1 absolute top-0 right-0 transform rotate-45 mt-2.5 mr-3 pointer-events-none"></div>
            @else
            <div
                class=" block text-xs text-left text-white bg-red-500 h-5 flex items-center p-1 rounded-md"
                role="alert"
            >
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="w-6 h-6 mx-1 stroke-current"
                >
                    <path
                        stroke-linecap="round"
                        stroke-linejoin="round"
                        stroke-width="2"
                        d="M12 9v2m0 4h.01m-6.938 4h13.856c1.54 0 2.502-1.667 1.732-3L13.732 4c-.77-1.333-2.694-1.333-3.464 0L3.34 16c-.77 1.333.192 3 1.732 3z"
                    ></path>
                </svg>
                No results
            </div>
            @endif
        @else
            {{--Loading spinner, https://tailwindcss.com/docs/animation--}}
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

Then inside the `HTML select` class component I got the following that is not working:

```
public function updateArea($new_area_id){
    $this->new_area_id = $new_area_id;
    $this->validate();

    $user = User::findOrFail($this->record_id);
    $area = Area::findOrFail($new_area_id);
    $user->area_id=$area->id;
    $user->save();//ERROR TRIGGERS HERE: General error 20018 UPDATE failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings 

    $this->emit('areaUpdated');
}
```

Error is:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 20018 UPDATE failed because the
> following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ANSI_NULLS,
> CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, ANSI_WARNINGS, ANSI_PADDING'. Verify that SET
> options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on
> computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications
> and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations. [20018]
> (severity 16) [update [user] set [area_id] = 6 where [id] = 4] (SQL:
> update [user] set [area_id] = 6 where [id] = 4)

Here is the config of the database connection:

**config/database.php**

```
'sqlsrv' => [
    'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
],
```

This error is weird, since, in the other `areas` datatable where I have implemented a similar inline content editable datatable, all the CRUD (insert, update, and delete) are working flawlessly.

In that other case, I got this `areas` datatable where I got explicit buttons to update and delete (which differs from my first datatable, where the user can click directly on the row to edit).

[image]

When the user clicks on the edit icon, the area name becomes editable input and then both `save` and `cancel` buttons appear.

[image]

Should the user click on save,

```
<td class="px-6 py-4 text-right text-sm font-medium">{{-- whitespace-nowrap--}}
   @if($editedInputId == $area->id)
       <div class="flex items-end">
           <div class="flex items-end">
                <button class="inline-flex items-center px-6 py-2 m-2 px-2 py-2 bg-blue-600 text-white rounded-lg  shadow-sm hover:bg-blue-500 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-200" wire:click.prevent="updateArea({{$area->id}})" wire:loading.attr="disabled" wire:target="updateArea" class="disabled:opacity-25">
                    <div wire:loading wire:target="updateArea" style="border-top-color:transparent" class="w-4 h-4 border-4 border-gray-300 border-solid rounded-full animate-spin"></div>
                         <span class="ml-2">SAVE</span>
                 </button>
                 <x-jet-secondary-button wire:click="cancelEdit" class="ml-2">CANCEL</x-jet-secondary-button>
           </div>
       </div>
{{-- ... --}}
```

an update area method is triggered

```
public function updateArea($editedInputId){
    $this->validate();

    $area = Area::findOrFail($editedInputId);
    $area->name = $this->name;

    $area->save();

    $this->empty();
}
```

And the updating process works perfectly.

How do I fix that error in the first datatable? What am I missing? What should I try out? Any workaround out there?

Answer (score 1):

I had to log in into the MSSQL Server, USE the desired database and then execute the following commands:

```
ALTER DATABASE CURRENT SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON;
GO

ALTER DATABASE CURRENT SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON;
GO

ALTER DATABASE CURRENT SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON;
GO

ALTER DATABASE CURRENT SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
GO
```

And that did the trick.

Official docs about it, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).